# SQL Server 2005 SSIS padding TAB-delimited results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssis

When I execute a simple SELECT * FROM... query (seven columns) in Management Studio and then save the results as a TAB-delimited text file, the resulting file is generated and delimited properly, but when I run the same query in SSIS to produce the same text file, it insists on right-padding all varchar columns with spaces. It delimits properly, but column values take up their full column width of space, similar to a fixed-width format.

I tried setting the text file data connection to ragged-right instead of delimited, but in that case it doesn't allow me to specify TAB as the delimiter.

I'm trying to figure out what is different in the way SSIS formats the output from the output from Management Studio.

Comment: Can you paste the table schema?

Comment: It's actually a view based on a few different tables. All but one of the columns from those tables are varchar, with the one being char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SSIS setup sounds like it should work as you want it to do.  You should be able to select the delimited format (ragged right shouldn't be necessary).

Can you check your source data to see if there are trailing spaces in the values?  Trailing spaces can exist even in the varchar data type.  If you have trailing spaces in the data, you can use the `RTRIM()` function in your source query to get rid of them.

Comment: No trailing spaces in the data. I'm quite puzzled by the difference in the TAB-delimited product of Management Studio vs. the SSIS TAB-delimited text file connection. I can't figure out why they should produce different results. Don't they both use the same libraries?